# Bi-gram model to predict text

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, n-gram

I am planning to implement bi-gram model to predict a search text. If a user has frequently searched "Test search word" and then if user types "Test" I am looking to automatically suggest "Test search word"

I have the list of data of searched text. I am trying with bi-gram as even if user types "Tast" it should still provide "Test search word". I am implementing it in Java. I am looking for a library to supply the data that I have and when I pass the user keyed in text, it should provide the prediction.

After research I found below links

- https://www.javatips.net/api/Solbase-Lucene-master/contrib/analyzers/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.java
- https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/ngram/NGramUtils.html

but they are not helping in my case. Are there any Java libraries that suits my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of two solutions:

**First**

- Index each of your user string queries in a [MARISA](http://www.s-yata.jp/marisa-trie/docs/readme.en.html) (Matching Algorithm with Recursively Implemented StorAge) TRIE data structure (data structure optimised for keywords search and autocomplete).
- Prepare a Levenshtein distance measurement method to tolerate typos.

Now for each new user query `q`, get all strings indexed in MARISA TRIE that has your query `q` as **prefix** (after typo tolerance).

**Second**

Use a elasticsearch suggester

Documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester

Please notice that parts of the suggest feature are still under development.